# MySQL pagination with search function, mysql_num_rows or mysql_fetch row?

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, search-engine, rows

I'm eating myself for a while about this code. Before I continue, I really don't expect the codes to be rewritten, just help me to get to the right direction because I'm lost ^^

So this is the code I use for querying out lists. $showitemsperlist can be set my the user, which shows many items should be shown per page..

```
if (isset($_GET["page"])) 
{ 
$page  = $_GET["page"]; 
} 
else 
{ 
$page=1; 
}; 
$start_from = ($page-1) * $showitemsperlist; 

// THIS SECTION IS THE 'search' section. Items are shown according to user input.
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    $search = $_POST['search'];
    $terms = explode(" ", $search);
    $customerlistquery = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM customer
    LEFT JOIN company
    ON customer.compid=company.compid
    WHERE
    ";
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($terms as $each) 
    {
        if ($i++ > 0) 
        $customerlistquery .= ' OR ';

        $customerlistquery .= "concat(custsurname, custforename, custmidname, custpostal, custphone1, custphone2, custfax, custnamecode) LIKE '%$each%' ";
    }
    $customerlistquery .= " ORDER BY $orderby ASC LIMIT $start_from, $showitemsperlist" ;

}
else
// IF NOT SEARCHING, JUST SHOW EVERYTHING.
{
    $customerlistquery = "  
            SELECT *
            FROM customer
            LEFT JOIN company
            ON customer.compid=company.compid
            ORDER BY $orderby
            ASC LIMIT $start_from, $showitemsperlist
            ";
}

// EXECUTE QUERY:
$result=mysql_query($customerlistquery) or die("query fout " . mysql_error() );
```

The queries are working and all, but below this I use this lines of code to count the pages:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(custid) FROM customer"; 
$rs_result = mysql_query($sql); 
$row = mysql_fetch_row($rs_result); 
$total_records = $row[0]; 
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $showitemsperlist); 
echo "<p id='pagination'>";
if ($total_pages < 2)
{
    echo "<br/>";
}
else
{
    echo "Page: ";
    for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) 
    { 
        echo "<a href='crm_custlist.php?page=".$i."' id='pagination'>".$i."</a>"; 
    }
}
echo "</p>";
```

I see 1 problem here, that is the $sql when executing 'search' function. If I'm not executing the 'Search', I do get the page links, when I'm not 'searching' I get them too, because it's static...Not adapted to the 'search' query.

So I tried to change $rs_result = mysql_query($sql); to ...($customerlistquery), becuase it should count the results found there, but this gives me alot more pages than it should!

Next I tried to change fetch_row to num_rows, which returns the difference between the ASC limits, so that doesn't help.

So I need to count the total results, can't be something else.

What I really don't understand:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(custid) FROM customer"; 
$rs_result = mysql_query($sql); 
$row = mysql_fetch_row($rs_result); 
$total_records = $row[0];
```

returns 27 values. SELECT (custid) FROM customer returns 27 values too...So I figured it out. I need somehow to have an additional COUNT(custid) field in the $customerlistquery, which returns the total amount and that can be used as $total_records. (At least I think I figured it out.)

The best option would be to mysql_num_rows to return the total records found, but this is now impossible because of the ASC LIMIT...

I'm totally stuck here. Any help is welcome!!!

Thanx.

EDIT: 31-10-2012 - 11:50

Ok I found it. I need to use SELECT COUNT(*) for the $customerlistquery and replace ...($sql) with: $rs_result = mysql_query($customerlistquery);.

This returns the values I do need. But now all the fields I want to echo out are Undefined indexes.

Using these lines below to define the indexes...Working with SELECT *, not with SELECT COUNT(*):

```
while( $record=mysql_fetch_array($result) ) 
{
$custid=$record['custid'];
$compid=$record['compid'];
$compname=$record['compname'];
$custsurname=$record['custsurname'];
```

EDIT: 31-10-2012 - 12:06

Very close now! Trying to add a new table row which is COUNT(*) to my $customerlistquery...
Trying everything ^^ soon it will work...I hope.

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer
LEFT JOIN company
ON customer.compid=company.compid
WHERE
( SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM customer )
```

Not sure what I'm doing, need a little time just informing my progress before comments become are irrelevant..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why didn't you debug like that

```
while( $record=mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
echo '<pre>";
print_r($record);
echo "</pre>";
}
```

and see your $record

Comment: True. Pretty stupid of me. But found the problem by running the query in phpmyadmin. Now I just need to place a COUNT(*) as (table1) in my records field (for all records). Figuring that out now, then it should work probably.